# Integral of Gaussian PDF

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals, random-variables, gaussian-integral

I have tried to solve the following integral in closed form:
(I encountered this on approximating a CRLB)

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \phi(x) \phi(a+bx) dx
\end{equation}

where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is the pdf of a standard Gaussian Random Variable.
Using the 'integration by parts' and Owen's 'a table of normal integrals' I found following solution, but integrating the function Numerically (In Matlab) gives me different values. Can any body help me? There must be problem with my closed-form solution

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} x^2 \phi(x) \phi(a+bx) dx= \frac{1}{(1+b^2)^{3/2}} ~ \phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Using Mathematica, I find that the rational function in front of your result should have a numerator of $1+b^2+a^2 b^2$ rather than $1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Unfortunately my Numerical evaluation is still different with your suggested numerator

Comment: I rechecked my Mathematica, and I'd misread it: the function in front of the PDF in the result would be $$ \frac{1+b^2+a^2b^2}{(1+b^2)^{5/2}} = \frac{1}{(1+b^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{a^2 b^2}{(1+b^2)^{5/2}}$$ (i.e. the power in the denominator would be $5/2$ not $3/2$). So you might check to see if that works.

Comment: @Semiclassical   I believe it's true , Thanks